# "TypeError: read() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)" when trying to use read() from subclass

Tags: python, inheritance, serial-port, super

I'm writing a class which extends pySerial's `serial.Serial` class, and I'm having trouble using the `readline()` function.

I'm able to reproduce the problem with as little code as this:

```
import serial
class A(serial.Serial):
    def read(self):
        return super(A, self).readline()

a = A()
a.read()
```

When I run this code, I get a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in read
TypeError: read() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I know I'm missing something here. I would expect it to pass just one argument (`self`). Where does the second argument come from?

Also, I tried using `inspect.getcallargs(a.read)` to figure out that second argument, but I then got this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 900, in getcallargs
    args, varargs, varkw, defaults = getargspec(func)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 815, in getargspec
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a Python function'.format(func))
TypeError: <built-in method readline of A object at 0xecf3d0> is not a Python function
```

This makes some sense, assuming PySerial's `readline()` is a native C function or system call. Am I correct in assuming this is why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Serial.read()` accepts an optional argument, `size`, whose default value is 1. Presumably `Serial.readline()` calls the `read()` method using this argument.  You've overridden `read()`, but you haven't given your version the `size` argument, so you get an error when `readline()` calls your version of `read()`.

When you fix the error, you'll probably have a problem with recursion;  I suspect the `read()` method should not call `readline()`.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes a lot of sense. I'd really like to keep my `read` function named `read`, but I don't particularly feel like re-writing or overriding `readline`. Is there a way to make the superclass' `readline` use the proper `read`?

Comment: I'd suggest that you don't call your method `read`.  Or, instead of subclassing (which implies an "is a" [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a] relationship between `A` and `Serial`, and so the signature and use of `read` should not change), use composition (i.e. `A` "has a" [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a] `Serial` instance), and then your `read` method can happily call the `readline` method of the `Serial` instance with no worries.